# Turn off yellow popup windows

Tags: eclipse, user-interface

How do you turn off those yellow pop-up windows that appear whenever you leave the mouse cursor over some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse 3.7.2 you can go to menu Window->Preferences, then expand Java/Editor and select Hovers.

There uncheck all checkboxes (combined hover, etc).

Comment: Thanks so much, I was looking in the General Editors sections thinking it was there.